# Using ActionBarSherlock & ViewPagerIndicator Synchronously Will Not Compile

Tags: android, dalvik, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

When using ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator at the same time I am getting the below error; from what I've read - it's caused due to conflicting/duplicate libraries in the two.

One solution was to have ABS rely on VPI (Or the other way around, I tried both) but this still gave me the same error even after a clean and rebuild. Right now I'm just working in two separate projects so I can get my work done - but I'd like to combine them obviously ha. Help would be much appreciated!

```
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:702)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:646)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-04-19 00:39:20 - MashableReader] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:**
Alright - as the answer below gets at, the issue was the dependency resolution in the Eclipse ADT. Basically my solution was to make the ViewPagerIndicator rely on ActionBarSherlock (Meaning, in the VPI properties, I add ABS to the project like you would for a regular project - for those of you who might be thinking backwards). I still had issues with that when I was getting errors in my code saying some of the methods couldn't be overridden - this part is because you have the wrong imports, so delete all your imports and CRTL+SHIFT+O (Quick import resolution) and select all the ones from the android.support.v4 packages and you should be all good on that. But then I still ran into the original Dalvik issue - to fix this I had to go into the actual folder where my VPI library was and delete the support jar from the /libs folder to stop it from grabbing it - then all set :)

Comment: @CommonsWare - Just checked, all up to date.

Comment: when you say add ABS to VPI, do you also imply to remove the ref to support from VPI (since it will get it from ABS)?

Comment: just adding ABS as a library to VPI gives me the multi reference error...

Comment: @towpse - If I remember right, I removed the support jar from VPI and then included ABS as a library. A lot could have changed since I last touched this though.

Comment: @TJ Biddle - that was my first thought as well, to remove the support from VPI. it seems intuitive on how to add jars, but not so much removing them. unless i remove all android dependencies via the JavaBuildPath->Libraries tab. i can't seem to just select the support jar and delete or remove it.

Comment: @towpse - That's exactly what you do :p

Comment: @TJ Biddle: oh ya. and then when adding the ASB, that's just adding an android library or is it adding a jar library dependency?

Comment: It was either: Add ABS to your project and have the ABS project depend on VPI - or the other way around (Add VPI to your project, and have the VPI project depend on ABS). I'd check, but I don't have the projects I did this on on my laptop.

Comment: @TJ okay i think i got it. thanks for the thread!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the problem is both ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator use libs/android-support-v4.jar dependency.

The simplest solution is upgrade your work station to latest Android SDK and Eclipse ADT plugin version (at least r17), as this situation is automatically handled by the SDK now (since r17), see the [r17 changelog](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects):

> #### Dependency resolution
>
> When a project references two Library projects that both require the same jar file, the build system has to detect and resolve the duplication.

Also Note that since r17, all jar file under libs folder are automatically populated to project's classpath, you don't need manually add them to project's build path anymore, also mentioned in the [r17 changelog](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects):

> Projects have source folders, as well as Library Project and jar file dependencies. With no other setup needed than adding Library Projects as a dependency in project.properties, a project’s classpath is automatically populated with:
>
> - The content of the project’s libs/*.jar
> - The output of the Library Projects.
> - The Library Projects’ libs/*.jar

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm, I appreciate the detailed response - but I just checked and I have R19 for the Android SDK and v18 for the Eclipse ADT Plugin.

Comment: Check you project build path, make sure you are not explicitly include android-support-v4.jar as external jar libraries second time.

Comment: Weird, my last shot is check out and see if android-support-v4.jar from both library projects are identical, as mentioned in changelog: _Currently our detection is very basic, checking only that the files are identical in size and sha1. If two libraries each include in their libs folder a file called mylib.jar but these two files are different, then the build system will fail indicating a dependency error._

Comment: If you're using the latest from each project they **will not** be identical. You should update the `.jar` in VPI to r7. This will be reflected in its next release.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Is there a simple way to do this? Tried a few different things and had to restore a dropbox backup since I was screwing around with it too much lol. Android > Add Support Library (Which prompts for R7) gives me this error, which I'll continue to work on: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4410

Comment: Finally got this. I'll update my original question for any others who stumble upon this. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the latest version of ADT, SDK etc and it still has this problem - it still doesn't seem to know which support library to use from which dependent library etc.

TJ's solution does work but I used an alternate approach.

My solution was the following:

1. Went into each library project and main application project that references the library and deleted the libs/android-support-v4.jar reference
2. Went back into each project and dragged the android-support-v4.jar from the filesystem (on my Mac, I store the SDK in my documents folder: Users//Documents/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86/extras/android/compatibility/v4/android-support-v4.jar) onto the libs folder and choose to LINK to the jar instead of copying it into the project.
3. Now all my projects reference the same .jar file on my filesystem and if I update the support library in the future (via the Android SDK Manager), the .jar will be updated and the projects in turn will pull in the latest jar.

So updating the support library should not break anything and allow you to be on the latest version.