# ViewPagerIndicator drawable resource not found

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I have a project that is using both `ActionBarSherloc`k and `ViewPagerIndicator`.  I had some issues including both as a library, so what I ended up doing was making `ViewPagerIndicator` include `ActionBarSherlock` as a library and remove the support v4 jar from `ViewPagerIndicator` (see this post:  [Using ActionBarSherlock & ViewPagerIndicator Syncronously Will Not Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236242/using-actionbarsherlock-viewpagerindicator-syncronously-will-not-compile)).

Everything builds and my app runs, but when I inflate a view with a `TabIndicator`, a resource not found exception is thrown.  I've traced it down to the `vpi__tab_indicator.xml` file and the 6 drawables it's referencing.  When I comment out those drawables, the view inflates fine.  I can see these drawables in both the `ViewPagerIndicator` project, as well as in its `R` file in my application.  Is there something that I'm missing?  The activity in question has the following style:  `android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults"`

**Edit:**
stack trace (if it helps any)

> 07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.Activity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/vpi__tab_indicator.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02005a
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/vpi__tab_indicator.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02005a
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1918)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.view.View.(View.java:3336)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:447)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator$TabView.(TabPageIndicator.java:252)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.addTab(TabPageIndicator.java:152)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged(TabPageIndicator.java:209)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.setViewPager(TabPageIndicator.java:197)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at com.myapp.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:27)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   ... 11 more
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:524)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:278)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:186)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
>   07-30 14:48:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1915)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When copying files from one place to the other, a couple of my `ViewPagerIndicator` drawables must have gotten corrupted along the way.  I re-fetched the drawables from the repo, added them into the project, everything compiled and ran perfect.

Hopefully that will save someone else a few hours.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have the same issue in my bug reports. I re-added the vpi library (using jake w's library), will confirm if it resolved my issue.